# How can I change my code to print this using just the print statement?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm trying to write a program that prints out exactly the following, where the values in < .... > are replaced by the actual value inside the variables. However, you can only use ONE print statement.

```
// The variable 'a' has value of <a>. //
\\ While the variable 'b' has value of <b>. \\
// Lastly, the variable 's' has value of "<s>". //
```

Example, if `a=1, b=1.5` and `s='hi'`, then the expected output is:

```
// The variable 'a' has value of 1. //
\\ While the variable 'b' has value of 1.5. \\
// Lastly, the variable 's' has value of "hi". //
```

I'm kinda struggling to grasp a concept here I'm not gonna lie, which is why my code is like this... what should I change?

```
s = '// The variable 'a' has value of <2> . //\n \\ While the variable 'b' has value of <3> . \\ \\n// Lastly, the variable 's' has value of <"hello">. //''
print int(float(a, b, c))
```

Comment: ``print(f"// The variable 'a' has value of <{a}> . //\n \\ While the variable 'b' has value of <{b}> . \\ \\n// Lastly, the variable 's' has value of <{s}>. //")``

Comment: First you should remove the syntax errors. Use an IDE that tells you where the syntax errors are. Pycharm Community Edition is a good choice

Comment: What have you been taught? Do you know strings, f-strings? replace()?

Comment: @ThomasWeller yep I have learnt abt f-strings and replace

Comment: Okay, then use one of it, or even both. You haven't done that anywhere.